# KeySet pagination with Blazebit use offset

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to do pagination on keySet and use framework.

That framework is called Blaze Persistence, and it supports Keyset Pagination for JPA entity queries.

Pagination should take place without using offset , but I see offset in the request

```
keysetPage = new DefaultKeysetPage(cursorKey.getFirstResult(), pageSize, keySetLowest, keySetHighest);
```

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilder
            .orderBy(
                    "titile",
                     ASC
            )
            .orderBy(
                    "id",
                    ASC
            )
            ..page(keysetPage, pageNumber * pageSize, pageSize)
                .getResultList();`
```

but in hibernate log I see that the query uses offset

`Hibernate: select h1_0.id,h1_0.description,h1_0.group_id,h1_0.icon,h1_0.participants_count,h1_0.title from hobby_type_entity h1_0 where (h1_0.title, ?) < (?, h1_0.id) and 0=0 order by h1_0.title desc,h1_0.id offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only`

how can I make a pagination without using offset ?